# iOS LLVM and Clang sys/_types.h file not found

Tags: c++, ios, compilation, clang

After installing LLVM and Clank from a cydia repo I am trying to compile a c++ program using iTerminal

I am running the following command with the following result:

```
~ mobile$ clang++ test.cpp

In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:64:
/usr/include/_types.h:27:10: fatal error:
'sys/_types.h' file not found
#include <sys/_types.h>
^
1 error generated
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

}
```

How do I fix this?

This code is being written, compiled, and (soon to be) run entirely on an ipod touch.

Comment: Where have you installed the compiler? Have you setup your include paths to this location? Using a custom install of a compiler can be tricky. Are you running into a problem using Xcode and the command line developer tools?

Comment: This compiler is installed on an ipod touch. I don't use xcode. And yes my problem is the compiler isnt seeing all of the headers installed. as for custom... How do i set those up correctly? And do i need to?